# Active record query for finding products in each city

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-record-query

I have two models as given below. Address table has an attribute city. Is it possible to find out total no. of products in each city using active record queries or do can it be done only through native sql query?

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :address
    end

    class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :products
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
 @no_of_products= Product.joins(:address).group("adrresses.city").count
```

Comment: This is fine but there are more than 200 cities. I wanted to get product count of each city with one query

Answer (score 1):

Try this way for all records for all `city`

```
Product.joins(:address).group("adrresses.city").count
```

It will return you output like

```
{"city1" => 100, "city2" => 200}
```